# How does one block a website such that it cannot be easily unblocked?

Tags: linux, macos

I have found the internet to be a massive time sink for me.
My efforts to block the websites that are utterly useless to me have been vain for the simple reason that, if I am bored enough, I will bypass the block.

All I can think of is to use the hosts file and a file monitor to ensure it has a loopback in place every time it is edited.

Note: I run Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) is a productivity extension for Google Chrome that helps you stay focused on work by restricting the amount of time you can spend on time-wasting websites. Once your allotted time has been used up, the sites you have blocked will be inaccessible for the rest of the day.

It is highly configurable, allowing you to block or allow entire sites, specific subdomains, specific paths, specific pages, even specific in-page content (videos, games, images, forms, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could block the website on your router, assuming you have a firmware that allows for it. You could make a long, not easily typed password to the router and then it would (hopefully) so inconvenient that you wouldn't bother changing it when you're bored. On the other hand, you could just not go on these sites.

Comment: If bored-me could remain on task, productive-me would not have to do this.  Also, I lack a router, so I cannot use that method.    That said, I am willing to purchase a router. Should I buy with dd-wrt in mind?

Comment: I did have dd-wrt in mind. I have used iptables on it in the past and setting up a simple block like this would be a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a crontab task which checks and updates the hosts file every few minutes.  You can obfuscate the job and script to make it more time consuming to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://www.rescuetime.com/

Supposedly their product is designed for this purpose.